# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.: Identity is pulling rom my local Windows login vs the website login I'm testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, logout, master-pages

Scenario: I have Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. I am testing the Logout functionality of my website when no one is authenticated (Guest mode, so to speak).

site.master.cs code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        TopBox.Text = "Welcome " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        RegisterLabel.Visible = false;
        Menu1.Visible = true;
        Menu2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        TopBox.Text = "Welcome, Guest.";
        RegisterLabel.Visible = true;
        Menu1.Visible = false;
        Menu2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

site.master code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var t;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

    function logout() {

        try {
            document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
            window.location.href = window.location.protocol.replace(/\:/g, '') + "://" + window.location.host + "Account/Login.aspx";
        }
        catch (e) { }

    }

    function resetTimer() {
        window.clearTimeout(t);
        t = window.setTimeout(logout, 900000);
    }
</script>
```

<%--Framework scripts--%>
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                <%--Site scripts--%>
                <%----%>

```
        </Scripts>

    </asp:ScriptManager>


    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <p style="float: left">
                <br />
            </p>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="RegisterLabel" runat="server" Text="Register">
                           <a style="font-size:small; color:white; align-content:center" href="Account/Register.aspx" >
                               Not Registered? Sign Up
                           </a>
            </asp:Label>
            <br />
            <div>
                <p>
                    <a class="MasterMenu" style="color: #A90000; font-size: larger" runat="server" href="~/">Following High School Football</a>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="TopBox" Font-Size="Small" Text="" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:Label>
                </p>

                <asp:Menu ID="Menu2" class="dropmenu" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%; font-size: 12px;"
                    BackColor="Transparent"
                    StaticDisplayLevels="2" StaticHoverStyle-BackColor="ForestGreen" StaticMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding="1px"
                    StaticMenuItemStyle-ItemSpacing="1px" StaticMenuItemStyle-Width="100%" Font-Size="Large"
                    StaticMenuItemStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" StaticMenuItemStyle-Height="40px">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Account/Login.aspx" Text="Login" Value="Login"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Account/Register.aspx" Text="Register" Value="Register"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Account/Recovery.aspx" Text="Password" Value="Recovery"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>

                </asp:Menu>

                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" class="dropmenu" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%; font-size: 12px;"
                    BackColor="Transparent"
                    StaticDisplayLevels="2" StaticHoverStyle-BackColor="ForestGreen" StaticMenuItemStyle-HorizontalPadding="1px"
                    StaticMenuItemStyle-ItemSpacing="1px" StaticMenuItemStyle-Width="100%" Font-Size="Large"
                    StaticMenuItemStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" StaticMenuItemStyle-Height="40px">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Records.aspx" Text="Records" Value="Records"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Pickem.aspx" Text="Pick Em" Value="Pick Em"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="Favorites" Value="Favorites"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Account/Logoff.aspx" Text="Logoff" Value="Logoff"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>

                </asp:Menu>

            </div>
        </div>

    </header>

    <div id="body">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
        </section>
    </div>

    <footer style="position: absolute; bottom: -240px; width: 98%; left: 136px; height: 63px;">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-right">
                <br />
                <br />
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - FHSF </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</form>
```

web.config

```
      <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true"></anonymousIdentification>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="SqlServicesConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
          <add name="UserDetailID" type="int" />
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="SqlServicesConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="SqlServicesConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="SqlServicesConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependantAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name='EntityFramework' culture="neutral" PublicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect  oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0"/>
      </dependantAssembly> 
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

RESULT: My Windows login is showing up as being the authenticated user, when that is not my intent. I want to be able to determine authenticated users within the application only. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Most likely you are using Windows auth for the site and as result requests are automatically authenticated. [edit] post to show corresponding portion of web.config to help someone to answer your question.

Comment: Added web.config code per Alexei's suggestion.

Comment: Would like to give Guest the ability to go to Default.aspx page and Login. aspx. I could achieve this by hiding the menu that accesses the other web pages, but that would not prevent them from typing in the subdomain in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

A typical ASP.NET web forms authentication scheme will work as follows:

1. After the user successfully signs on, the web site sets a cookie representing the authenticated user or session.  ASP.NET offers the [forms authentication ticket and cookie](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910443) or you can roll your own.
2. Each and every HTTP request is intercepted (via the `Authenticate` event) by an [HttpModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178468.aspx) to parse/decrypt the cookie and set [HttpContext.User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx) to an object that represents the current user.  As you have discovered, this does not happen by itself.  You can roll your own module, or use [Microsoft's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. Then and only then can your application user the HttpContext.User property to determine the current user's identity.  If you skip steps 1 & 2, the HttpContext.User property returns the identity of the user assigned to the execution context of the [App Pool](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2245511/IIS-and-ASPNET-The-Application-Pool.htm), which in this case is you, probably because you are running the site locally.

Here is a [cookbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301240#bookmark-4) for doing it with built-in ASP.NET forms authentication.  You should also be able to generate a web site that uses forms authentication by using the new project wizard.

Comment: I have found that I was, unknowingly, trying to use both Membership and Identity in terms of security. I discovered that there are differences of which this article points out. https://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/   In short, I don't believe I need the forms method as membership is probably all that should be required.